# Why do we say a "hotel room" and not a "hotel's room"?

Tags: possessives, compounds, attributive-nouns

I would like to know what the rule is to explain why we do not use the genitive construction *hotel's room*. Instead, we say "a hotel room".

Other examples:

- a hospital bed
- a bike stand

Would it suffice to ask "What kind of..."?

Comment: Hotel, hospital, etc. are serving as adjectives.  You'd be correct but awkward saying hotel's.

Comment: You mean 'modifiers'. 'Adjective' is a grammatical category and these aren't adjectives (e.g. you can't say "a more hotel room" or "the bikest stand").

Comment: @DavidM question is about genitive vs attributive nouns; might be simple but how is it off-topic? Almost all grammar-related questions can be answered through commonly-available references, but in that case [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) should be changed

Comment: @msam it's still general reference.

Comment: @DavidM in that case almost all grammar-related questions should be closed. Not trying to be provocative but the line between what is accepted and what is off-topic is not well-defined and seems to be totally subjective.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your examples use nouns that are used to modify other nouns (attributive nouns).
Possessive (also called Saxon Genitive) constructions, on the other hand, show possession [in the extended (my bike's front wheel) rather than just the proprietorial (John's bike) sense].

"a hotel's room" - a room belonging to a hotel

"a hotel room" - a specific type of room, somehow related to hotels (in this case also usually belonging to the hotel but that is not necessarily important)

similarly "hospital's bed", vs "hospital bed"

- We have three beds from central supplies and one from King Edward VII Hospital. The hospital's bed must be returned by May 2.
- A hospital bed can be identified by the fact that it may be raised electrically.
- There are an additional 10 000 new hospital beds in the new Nightingale hospitals. [Here, *beds* may mean *beds*, ie *spaces*, available.]

"the bike's stand" would imply that the stand belongs to the bike while "bike stand" describes a type of stand that is somehow related to bikes (of course, here, designed to house bikes).

Comment: Remember that these are not actually a genitive case like *yours, mine*, and *ours*, but rather are the result of applying an apostrophe-s clitic to the entire noun phrase. “The guy standing in front of the hotel’s hat just blew off.”  Calling *hotel’s* there some sort of genitive really does not make any sense at all.

Comment: @tchrist While the clitic vs genitive issue is highly debatable I changed the answer slightly to avoid confusion (even though the post being closed it probably makes no difference at all)

Comment: Attributive nouns have various semantic roles, and this may lead to ambiguity. A 'hospital bed' may mean a bed manufactured for use in a hospital (and maybe still awaiting delivery), bed 6 on ward 10, or even a space for a new patient.