# Should this name for an organization contain an apostrophe?

Tags: grammar, proper-nouns, titles

We're looking to start a small brewery and have decided to call it "Loons Landing". I'm wondering if perhaps it would be more correct to call it "Loon's Landing". I know that, as a business, we're able to call our business anything we want and correctness is subjective, but, because I'm curious about grammar, I'm wondering which spelling would present it as meaning "This is a spot where loons (as in the bird) land at (or perhaps *did* land at, some time in the past".

I sometimes have difficulty with apostrophes and whether they are necessary, especially in proper nouns, so I'm looking for some guidance here.

Comment: It's not clear if you're asking what you *should* use, or what the difference is. Nobody can tell you what you should use. See [Why do we say a “hotel room” and not a “hotel's room”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/159545/291924) for the difference.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yeah, you're right that it's not clear what I'm asking. I was trying to gauge opinion on whether "Loon's Landing" or "Loons Landing" was _more_ correct, but I suspect that an SE question isn't the right place for this.

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple loons landing at the site then the apostrophe should go after the letter s: *Loons’ Landing.*

If it’s a single Loon then *Loon’s Landing* is correct.

[apostrophe usage](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/topics/zvwwxnb/articles/zx9ydxs)

Comment: The question is asking if an apostrophe should be used at all, not where it should go if it is used … (Although this would be a good addendum if you were to explain why the possessive is more appropriate in the first place.)