# Consumers vs consumers' vs consumer's?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

The biggest gap between technology development and its tangible impact on consumer markets is the **(is it consumers, consumer's or consumers'?)** awareness of the product and their education on how and why it would benefit them.

Comment: **Not** the attributive noun (singular form or plural). I'd strongly favour the generic singular possessive (consumer's) here, using singular _their_ and _them_, but some may complain about that being odd so I might opt for the plural possessive. ////  However, there's arguably an incongruous zeugma (_their awareness of the product ... their education [ie being educated]_).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we say a "hotel room" and not a "hotel's room"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159545/why-do-we-say-a-hotel-room-and-not-a-hotels-room) (the best answer addresses when the reverse applies also)

Comment: Whose awareness in the "consumer markets" would increase other than the consumer? Also, educating the consumer on the benefits is not "education".

Comment: Choosing between "consumer's awareness" or "consumers' awareness" would depend on whether you're talking about educating the individual consumer or consumers as a group.